# Best CSV manipulation package for Laravel

Tags: php, csv, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a library to manipulate CSVs in my Laravel 5 app. I would like to choose one and stick to it for future development, so I'm looking for something good.

There's a lot of packages on [Packalyst](http://packalyst.com/s/csv). Do you have good experience with any of them? Would you recommend something specific?

Based on the number of downloads, [this one](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/pingpong/csv-reader) seems like a solid choice. Any opinions appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I have used [Laravel-Excel](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) and works very well.

From readme:

> It includes features like: importing Excel and CSV to collections,
>   exporting models, array's and views to Excel, importing batches of
>   files and importing a file by a config file.
>
> - Import into Laravel Collections
> - Export Blade views to Excel and CSV with optional CSS styling
> - Batch imports
> - A lot of optional config settings
> - Easy cell caching
> - Chunked importer
> - ExcelFile method injections
> - Editing existing Excel files
> - Advanced import by config files
> - and many more...

Comment: is this pacakge capable to export million of records?? if you are adding advantages of packaage make sure also mention the disadvantages of package

Answer (score 4):

I am using **[Laravel Excel v2.0.0 for Laravel 5](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs)**. This library has great documentation and is easy to use. I have used this library for CSV import and export for some projects without any problems.